# Is there a way to pass a variable to keypressed function?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, addeventlistener, dom-events, xul

I am trying to send the document and the control that the key was pressed in to the keypressed function.

Here is my code:

```
//Namespace
MyExt.BrowserOverlay = {
  init: function() {
        var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser
        if(appcontent)
              appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", MyExt.BrowserOverlay.onPageLoad, true);
  },

  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
                 var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
                 if (doc.location.href == "http://something.com"){
                     var txtBox = doc.getElementById('txtBox');
                      txtBox.addEventListener('keypress', keypressed, false); //Error Line
                                }
                 },
```

…

something like:

```
txtBox.addEventListener('keypress', keypressed(?,doc), false);
```

```
function keypressed(a,doc){
    alert(a); //a relates to keypress
    alert(doc.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to pass variable is to attach it to Element that will trigger event, but you can access document by using global variable `document`.

As for event listeners, browsers handle events differently:

> ```
> txtBox.someVar = "foobar"; // Any variable you want to pass
>
> if(window.addEventListener){ // Firefox, Chrome...
>  txtBox.addEventListener('keypress', keypressed, false);
> } else { // IE
>  txtBox.attachEvent('onkeypress', keypressed);
> }
> ```

> ```
> function keypressed(event){
>
>  // find event object
>  var e = event || window.event;
>
>  // find target object
>  var target = e.currentTarget;
>  if (e.target) target = e.target;
>  else if (e.srcElement) target = e.srcElement;
>  if (target.nodeType == 3) target = targ.parentNode;
>
>  // find key code
>  var code = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
>
>  alert(String.fromCharCode(code));
>  alert(target.someVar);
>  alert(document.body.innerHTML);
>
> }
> ```

Comment: (document) will not work in this case because multiple tabs are open, and possibly the same pages and elements. I don't want to modify all of them just the one that created the event. Can you return the document from the control that is on it? Unfortunately a global variable might be my only way out of this.

Comment: If you have `doc` variable, pass it like i passed `someVar`.

Comment: doc is not a global that can be used outside of the onPageLoad function, and keypressed is a private function outside of the MyExt.Browseroverlay namespace. 

var target = e.currentTarget; //Returns the control not the document.

I am trying to get both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gBrowser.contentDocument` to get the document of the currently selected tab.  See this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) on the tabbed browser control for more info.